# Glew - Linking Error on gl- function symbols when paired with GLFW

Tags: c++, glfw, glew

I was reworking a project to use GLFW in opposed to FreeGLUT, and I think I must've managed to delete something in my linker settings. I'm using GLEW, and while I initially thought I had untethered it somehow, its not giving me an error for all GLEW-related function calls, only a couple. I've checked the changes I made to property files using git, and the only change is replacing `freeglut.lib` with `glfwdll.lib`

The error messages:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBlendFunc@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDepthFunc@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnable@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16 referenced in function _main
1>Renderer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBindTexture@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Renderer::Render(unsigned int const &,unsigned int const &,struct RenderVariables const &,unsigned int const &,unsigned int const &)" (?Render@Renderer@@QAEXABI0ABURenderVariables@@00@Z)
1>Sprite.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBindTexture@8
1>Renderer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawArrays@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Renderer::Render(unsigned int const &,unsigned int const &,struct RenderVariables const &,unsigned int const &,unsigned int const &)" (?Render@Renderer@@QAEXABI0ABURenderVariables@@00@Z)
1>Sprite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGenTextures@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sprite::loadSprite(char *)" (?loadSprite@Sprite@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
1>Sprite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetFloatv@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sprite::loadSprite(char *)" (?loadSprite@Sprite@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
1>Sprite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTexImage2D@36 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sprite::loadSprite(char *)" (?loadSprite@Sprite@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
1>Sprite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTexParameterf@12 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sprite::loadSprite(char *)" (?loadSprite@Sprite@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
1>Sprite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTexParameteri@12 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sprite::loadSprite(char *)" (?loadSprite@Sprite@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
```

Then, my main() function, which is the only function that ended up changing during the transition:

```
void main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
if (!glfwInit())
{
    exit(-1);
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Space Invaders", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    endGame(-1);
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

// A call to glewInit() must be done after GLFW is initialized!
GLenum res = glewInit();
// Check for any errors
if (res != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
    endGame(1);
}

gameState = new GameState();

init();

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    pollInput(window);
    display();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
endGame(0);
}
```

I've noticed that each of the functions throwing errors have the gl- prefix rather than glew-, do I need to add another library now that I'm not using freeglut? I'm currently only linking glfw and glew.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm not sure how I managed without it before, but I needed to link `OpenGL32.lib` as well.